# Comparing Columns in Different CSV then Print Non-Matches

Tags: bash, csv, command-line-interface

I'm a scripting newbie and am looking for help in building a BASH script to compare different columns in different CSV documents and then print the non-matches. I've included an example below.

File 1
Employee ID Number,Last Name,First Name,Preferred Name,Email Address

File 2
Employee Name,Email Address

I am wanting to compare the email address column in both files. If File 1 does not contain an email address found in File 2, I want to output to a new file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks I was wondering what you were up to.  No seriously, SO is not a code writing service, have you tried anything?  Like loop on lines in file1 (research while), extract the email (research cut), grep that email in file2 (well grep!), if it's not there output to an output file (echo line >>newfile).  Good luck, if you get stuck, post your code so we can help.

Comment: Hello Nic3500 - Thanks for responding so quickly.

The first thing I tried was awk. I found a similar example on SO that I based my structure around, but am running into a syntax error near unexpected token '(':
`awk -f FNR == NR { mem[ $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 ] = 1; print next} { key = $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 if( ! ( key in mem) ) print}`

I also tried the follow grep:
`grep -vFxf file2.csv file1.csv > new.csv`

Grep kind of worked in the sense that it removed some entries, but not all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
>output.txt

# Read file2.txt, line per line...
cat file2.txt | while read line2
do
    # Extract the email from the line
    email2=$(echo $line2 | cut -d',' -f2)

    # Verify if the email is in file1
    if [ $(grep -c $email2 file1.txt) -eq 0 ]
    then
        # It is not, so output the line from file2 to the output file
        echo $line2 >>output.txt
    fi
done
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Haven't been sitting still waiting on you, kept trying in the meantime. Also came up with this: for em in `cut -d , -f 2 File2 |sort|uniq`; do sed -i.bak "/$em/d" File1 ; done

Sorry for the poor formatting, having difficulty with SO

Comment: No problem, comments are terrible for code, that is why it is always suggested to edit a question with code.

Answer (score 0):

Email addresses are case insensitive which should be a consideration when comparing them. This version uses a little awk to handle the case bit and with selecting the last field in each line (`$NF`):

```
#!/bin/bash

our_addresses=( $(awk -F, '{print tolower($NF)}' file1) )
while read -r line; do
    this_address=$(awk -F, '{print tolower($NF)}' <<< "$line")
    if [[ ! " ${our_addresses[@]} " =~ " $this_address " ]]; then
        echo "$line"
    fi
done < file2
```